# pass arguments (username, password) through /etc/fstab by using nfs

Tags: nfs, mount

I am using xubunte, 16.04
In /etc/fstab I added the line:

```
myserver:/open/for/everyone /foreveryoneonmycomputer          nfs    rw  0 0
```

This works. Now I want to mount my home partition from the server:

```
myserver:/somewhere/home /home/me/serverhome               nfs    username=me,password=mypasswd 0 0
```

When I remounted I got the answer: `mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified`

What is the misstake? I can't just use `rw` instead of these options because my username and password on my computer aren't equals to the ones for my account on the server.

Comment: Usually you mount all home directories at once and let NFS enforce access control. If your user ids do not match, if you were on NFSv4 you could set up id mapping. Do you have NFSv4 on the server?